# ../../page-name backend links are not rewritten

Tags: url-rewriting, links

UPDATE: when selecting images in the media library, the view command leads to a wrong URL in the form of domain-name.com/image, though the actual URL is properly stored on the image details.

On my website's backend I manually input backend links which are under the form of "../../page-name". Then on the front end the link becomes domain-name.com/page-name.

However after a plugin update all the links broke: they became "hardcoded" links leading to the URL "../page-name" without any domain name which is of course totally useless.

I thought the bug was related to said plugin but after restoring backup, updating a totally different plugin had the same effect. So did editing and saving changes on the page. Any of these changes cause this.

I removed the htaccess then regenerated but it changed nothing. Been trying to keyword research this issue to no avail, am not sure there is even a proper name for these backend soft links "../../page-name". Not sure this is related to a that rewriting file full of code or even where to being looking.

Am used to finding tutorials and information on what to input on which file to solve a given issue. Am not a coder but I've been doing wp maintenance for several sites for a while now and haven't had similar issues.

Comment: Are you mentioning this in menus  ? ie;  Custom menu items  ? If yes then they are are almost always full links.

Comment: No, menus are fine. This happens with buttons type of widgets.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.  **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy. Help them get to all the facts without asking follow up questions and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.